# How to show more than 4 fields in Salesforce Lightning Related List

Tags: page-layout, administration, related-list

[image: Related List]

Is possible show more than 4 fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to show more than 4 fields in the related list in lightning. You can show upto 10 fields in the related list by using Enhanced list in the lightning page.

```
Take your related lists to the next level. With Enhanced Related
Lists, now generally available, you can show up to 10 columns,
resize and sort your columns, perform mass actions, and wrap text.
```

Please find the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_enhanced_related_lists.htm&type=5&release=224) for the same.